# How to create Macro to conditionally print single cell contents row-by-row

Tags: excel, vba

Performing wifi antennae testing in manufacturing facility where values are recorded in a row for each part; I need to create an Excel Macro to print the cell contents to label based on true/false condition.

I've recording Macro just for printing step but unsure how to trigger the print job for a given cell in each row after data is entered.

I created one cell where if ALL the recorded values for each test are within tolerance, a resulting "PASS" or "FAIL" is entered.  What I want actually printed is an abbreviation of the serial number, so this formula is the basis of what SHOULD print after each part's values are recorded: 
=IF(K26="PASS", RIGHT(A26, 53), "FAIL"), which outputs C26-1-09-00194-12-0e.01.12.0c.0b-02.02.03.00.84.94.86, for instance.

for each row, based on result of PASS or FAIL, I need a label to print the serial number.  Basically just need to know how to trigger Macro for each row and the code for printing.

Comment: I don't understand what a "print job for a given cell" is. Do you want to print one cell?

Comment: Yes, that is correct; after the formula is applied and the result populates the cell, I want just that cell to print on a 2" x 1/2" label.  The user will then proceed to the next line, enter the wifi test values, formula is applied, another cell printed, ect,ect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your printing code in the change event of the worksheet (Worksheet_Change):

[image]

Remember to set the printing area to the cell you want to print.
Remember that the Target parameter is the cell that was changed.

See example below. You will have to set the PrintArea to the correct cell. Here I'm using the changed cell address which, if I understood correctly, is not the cell you want to print.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Target.Value = Target.Address

    Me.PageSetup.PrintArea = Target.Address
    Me.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

   Application.EnableEvents = True
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```